# Filtering json response with python list comprehension

Tags: python, json, list-comprehension

Given a json object with a many keys (properties?) like:

```
[{'name': 'Bob', 'infos': {'spam': 'eggs', 'foo': 'bar'}},
{'name': 'Tom'},
{'name': 'Lisa', 'infos': {'spam': 'qux', 'foo': 'baz'}}
...]
```

I am hoping to use a list comprehension to filter out entries where `entry['infos']['spam'] == 'eggs'`

I'd prefer a list comprehension if possible, but so far my only solution is to use multiple `.get()`s, with the ones furthest down the tree farthest to the right (to avoid `KeyError`s by making the statement `False` before it gets there).

For example,

```
# Will obviously fail with KeyError
[each for each in my_json if each['infos']['spam'] == 'eggs']

# Works but requires a separate / additional `.get()`, and only works
# because it is returning False before it evaluates all conditions
[each for each in my_json if each.get('infos') and each.get('infos').get('spam') == 'eggs']

# Fails as all conditions will be evaluated before running
[each for each in my_json if all([each.get('infos'), each.get('infos').get('spam') == 'eggs'])]

# Not a list comprehension, but concise... and also doesn't work
filter(lambda x: x['infos']['spam'] == 'eggs', my_json)
```

Is there any better way to filter my json responses? The reason I ask is that some APIs return json objects with the key of interest *deep* down... and having to use something like `each.get('a') and each['a'].get('b') and each['a']['b'].get('c') == 'd'` seems exhausting just to verify that `each['a']['b']['c'] == 'd'`.

I suppose I could always use a `try` `except KeyError`.

```
mylist = []
for each in my_json:
    try:
        if each['infos']['spam'] == 'eggs':
            mylist.append(each)
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Is there an obvious solution I'm missing (preferably within the python3 standard library) that would eliminate the redundancy in all the working solutions?

Comment: n.b. If [PEP 463](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0463/) happens, you can then do `[each for each in my_json if each['infos']['spam'] == 'eggs' except KeyError: False]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify a default to `get` in case no item exists for that key, so you could use

```
[each for each in my_json if each.get('infos', {}).get('spam') == 'eggs']
```

The first get `get('infos', {})` specifies an empty dict as the default so that the second get won't fail.

Here it is as a `filter`

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x.get('infos', {}).get('spam') == 'eggs', my_json)
[{'infos': {'foo': 'bar', 'spam': 'eggs'}, 'name': 'Bob'}]
```

Note these will still break if "infos" exists in the outer dict, but is not itself a dict.

A more robust method would be to define a filter function:

```
>>> def wonderful_spam(x):
...     try:
...             return x['infos']['spam'] == 'eggs'
...     except (KeyError, TypeError):
...             return False
...
>>> filter(wonderful_spam, my_json)
[{'infos': {'foo': 'bar', 'spam': 'eggs'}, 'name': 'Bob'}]
>>> [x for x in my_json if wonderful_spam(x)]
[{'infos': {'foo': 'bar', 'spam': 'eggs'}, 'name': 'Bob'}]
```

Comment: Maybe `x.get('infos', {}).get('spam', None)` is better? It will be difficult to distinguish between a `'spam':''` and a dictionary that doesnt have `'spam'` in it. But otherwsie great answer.

Comment: @ssm `None` is already the default for `get`, so you could just omit it ;) I'll edit the answer

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. I had though of using a default with `.get()` ,but the only one I had thought of was `.get('infos', None)`... which would make no difference. Giving it an empty dictionary for the next`.get()` to run on makes sense, thanks.